# Understanding when Elemental Overload beats CC/CD

Tags: path-of-exile

On the wiki page for [Elemental Overload](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Elemental_Overload), it lists a table that purportedly details the effectiveness of EO vs CC/CD builds.

[image]

What I don't understand is what the numbers mean. Is the red values stating the best opportunity to use EO over CD? Or is Red saying you are worse off playing EO over CD?

Comment: The top-left corner is the worst with lowest crit chance/multiplier. It will definitiely loose to overload. And it's red.

Comment: If you are building any sort of crit multi/crit chance then EO means you wasted those points on crit that you could use elsewhere. The only point I could see to this graph is if you are leveling a crit build, but your crit stats aren't quite good enough to beat out EO at that point.

Comment: At this point, my build isn't actively investing into crit multi unless it's on a notable with a attribute roll. I'm probably going to stick to EO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you do know that EO is a 40% multiplier. That will result in 1.4 times the damage. The numbers in the table are the multiplied base damage by certain critvalues.

Any value you see in that table that is under 1.400 (times your base damage) is less damage then just EO damage. So RED is where EO has higher value.

Still you can not just look at crit vs EO in a vacuum. It depends on so much more. For example whether your skill can even crit, if you do 100% of your damage as elemental or are you doing some of it as physical or chaos or if you can profit from different rolls on gear that will make gearing for crit extremely hard or even not worth it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "100% of your damage as elemental"?   I was considering trying a 100% phys to light static strike build -- would elemental overload work well?

Comment: EO only multiplies elemental damage. Elemental damage is fire, cold and lightning. So since you convert 100% of your damage to lightning you will do 0% as Physical or Chaos. That means every point of your damage will be multiplied by 1.4. If you for eample just do 50% lightning and 50% physical, EO would multiply your damage only by 1.2 since only 50% of your damage would get the 40% multiplier. [50x1 + 50x1.4 = 120]